# How to extract filenames from cmd input in python

Tags: python

I'm running a python program compiled on windows which receives files as input but have problems when I'm passing file names.

foo.py:

```
def main():
  args = sys.argv[1:]
  for i in args:
    print i
```

But when I compile and call it from the command line

```
\python foo.py *.html
```

It directly gives me the result of `*.html` which I hope to see a list of matching strings.

Can anyone hep plz:)

Comment: What shell are you using?  Many (such as BASH) will automatically expand `*.html` into the matching strings before calling `python`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use something called [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html). For a single filename what you are doing is fine. But if you want to loop through a file pattern, then use `glob`. It's basically a regex for files

```
import glob

glob.glob('*.html') #return all html files in curr dir
glob.glob('*')     # lists all files in the current directory python is running in
glob.glob('*.jpg')   # returns all jpeg images
glob.glob('[a-z]????.*')    # lists all files starting with a letter, followed by 4 characters (numbers, letters) and any ending.
```

So in your case -

```
import glob
def main():
   args = sys.argv[1:]
   for file in glob.glob(args):
       print i
```

Comment: @user1038662 glad to share what i knew. If this answer helped you then please make it as selected answer (Green tick mark on the left). helps the community. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) module will allow you to form paths correctly.